# What is wrong with my php explode?

Tags: php, string, split, explode

I have a string of html codes. Within this html code, i have a so called "html delimiter" which help to split the html code into smaller chunks.

The delimiter is in the format of

```
<br class="limit" />
```

The html code is as below

```
<p>To be A Premier in Global Distinction<br class="limit" />To be A Premier Polytechnic of Global Distinction&nbsp;<br class="limit" />We provide quality education and training to prepare students and adult learners for work and life, equipping them to be life-long learners <br class="limit" />We will harness our resources, expertise, creativity and innovation to support the development of business and industry.</p>
```

This is my php code

```
$htmlparts = explode("<br class='limit' />", $htmlcode);
echo $htmlparts [0];
echo $htmlparts [1];
echo $htmlparts [2];
```

By right $htmlparts [0] should return me

To be A Premier in Global Distinction, $htmlparts[1] should return me To be A Premier Polytechnic of Global Distinction  and so on.

By it fails to split. Appreciate any expert advice. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html sample has `"limit"`, while you're trying to explode `'limit'` - note the difference in quoting styles. Explode requires an EXACT match on the delimiter. Since you're using different quotes, there'll never be a match and therefore no explosion.

Comment: And by the way, use a real html parser.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I changed the <br class='limit' /> to <br class="limit" />, it still can't be split

Comment: Thanks all, i rechecked my code, it seems its the issue with the jquery grabbing of html code. I solved it. You guys are awesome!